# odoo 12 error - You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, odoo, odoo-12

I'm getting following error while loading my odoo 12 server on windows 7

> You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

But while loading through private window, it is loading!. Even though not able to create a database there.I'm getting following error at that time.

> Database creation error: relation "ir_model" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT * FROM ir_model WHERE state='manual' ^

I have installed postgresql 9.2 which I used for odoo 11 as well. Is there any specific version needed for odoo 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any official documentation to back this up, but the recommended version for Odoo 12 is **PostgreSQL 9.6+**.

If you're still having trouble once you get the newer version of PostgreSQL, then make sure you are following [the Odoo install documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/setup/install.html) as closely as possible.