# How to solve Odoo14 ir_model does not exist error?

Tags: odoo

I installed **`odoo14`** from git and use **`postgresql 13.1`**. I can't create database in odoo. It shows the following error:

```
odoo14 odoo.modules.loading: 1 modules loaded in 0.03s, 0 queries (+0 extra) 
2020-12-01 09:23:17,347 11700 ERROR Odoo14 odoo.sql_db: bad query: SELECT * FROM ir_model WHERE state='manual'
ERROR: relation "ir_model" does not exist
```

Comment: try odoo argument -i <database name>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [odoo 12 error - You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076327/odoo-12-error-you-dont-have-the-permission-to-access-the-requested-resource)

Comment: I have the same issue with odoo13 Enterprise and postgresql 11. Setup is on Apple M1 with postgresql in Docker container